# SQL Select list of tables in a database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2005. I am trying to SELECT a list of tables in one of my database. Here is my structure of my SQL Server:

```
- <IP>(SQL Server 9.0 -userlogin)
   - Databases
      - Company
          - Tables
             - dbo.UserDB
             - dbo.detailsDB
             - dbo.goodsDB
```

I would like to retrieve the values of `dbo.UserDB`, `dbo.detailsDB`, `dbo.goodsDB`

But i do not know what is the exact sql query needed.

I have tried many ways like

`SELECT * FROM userlogin.Tables;` and

`SELECT * FROM userlogin.Company.Tables;`, but none of them works.

I have seen quite a few posts which suggests using `show databases` and `show tables`, but they don't seem to work as well.

Is it possible to select a list of table names in a database in the first place?

Thank you for any help in advance.

---

Thanks for the MSDNA link that @TomTom provided, I can now list my tables in my database.

However, I would want to list specific tables where TABLE_NAME contains "user".

How can I do it? I am trying on the following sql but it is not displaying result at the moment:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME
FROM Company.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE '%"user"%';
GO
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try the iNFORMATION_SCHEMA.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186778.aspx

They contain all the schema information you need.

Comment: thanks for the useful link. I can now list all my databases. However, what if I want to list a database where name contains e.g. "user"? I am trying the following sql: SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME
FROM Company.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE '%"user"%';
GO

Comment: @RUiHAO - do you want to list a database or tables? Remove the " around user so `'%"user"%'` becomes `'%user%'`.

Comment: @Lieven Sorry my mistake, I want a list of tables. Your method worked. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 6):

Use the new `sys` system catalog in SQL Server 2005 and up:

```
SELECT Name
FROM sys.tables
WHERE is_ms_shipped = 0   -- only list *your* tables - not the system / MS table
```

You can read more about system catalog views and how to query them in the [MSDN Books Online](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174365.aspx) - and be warned - there's **lots** more to read and learn!

Answer (score 4):

You can use INFORMATION_SCHEMA as told by @TomTom:

```
USE <<YOUR_DB_NAME>>

SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + TABLE_NAME, *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
ORDER BY TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + TABLE_NAME
```

You can customize above query as per your requirements.

For your other question to find tables where the name contains 'user', execute the following statement:

```
USE <<YOUR_DB_NAME>>
Exec sp_tables '%user%'
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use this

```
Use ***database name***

SELECT *
FROM   sys.tables
WHERE name like '%user%'
```

Sorry, have seen that @marc_s has provided the answer before me!

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
SELECT *
from sysobjects 
where type = 'U' AND
NAME LIKE '%user%'
GO
```

Comment: Deprecated - you should use `sys.tables` as of SQL Server 2005 and up